# What does this NASA administrator's tweeted statement mean? What is the context?

Tags: nasa, crewed-spaceflight, commercial

**Background:** Teslarati's [NASA head calls out SpaceX CEO Elon Musk over Starship event in bizarre statement](https://www.teslarati.com/nasa-head-calls-out-spacex-ceo-elon-musk-starship-event/) might serve as a resource for answers if the question is successfully reopened.

---

**Question:** Would a similar statement about taxpayer money used in SLS/Boeing or the JWST (delays and cost overruns started circa 2011<sup>1</sup> and continue) be equally or more appropriate, or are delays with Commercial Crew even more egregious? Is this [Jim Bridenstine tweet](https://twitter.com/JimBridenstine/status/1177711106300747777) just a bit of "space snark" or do the sentiments reflect a legitimate beef?

<sup>1</sup>Cowen, Ron (25 August 2011). "[Webb Telescope Delayed, Costs Rise to $8 Billion](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114105805/http://news.sciencemag.org/scienceinsider/2011/08/webb-telescope-delayed-costs.html?ref=hp)". ScienceInsider. Archived from [the original](http://news.sciencemag.org/scienceinsider/2011/08/webb-telescope-delayed-costs.html?ref=hp) on 14 January 2012. (found in Wikipedia's [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope))

> My statement on @SpaceX's announcement tomorrow:
>
> [image: twitter.com/JimBridenstine/status/1177711106300747777]

Text in the image:

> I am looking forward to the SpaceX announcement tomorrow. In the mean time, Commercial Crew is years behind schedule. NASA expects to see the same level of enthusiasm focused on the investments of the American taxpayer. It’s time to deliver
>
> Administrator Jim Bridenstine

---

**update:** From CNN Business News' [NASA administrator tells Elon Musk's SpaceX 'it's time to deliver'](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/09/28/business/elon-musk-spacex-nasa-bridenstine-crew-dragon/index.html):

> Bridenstine also retweeted a comment from Ars Technica writer Eric Berger that said the statement did not read "as a shot to SpaceX, but rather a reflection of Jim's desire to see all NASA contractors meet their deadlines for government contracts."

Here's that [tweet](https://twitter.com/SciGuySpace/status/1177711302296395776):

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based. Given the multiple opinions posted on that twitter thread, there's no knowing what Bridenstine actually meant by that tweet.

Comment: @DavidHammen I think that's premature. You're presuming to know that *nobody* can write a fact-based answer. Why not give it a few days and see if someone can? Have you read my question in full, or did you stop after the first half of the title?

Comment: Honestly, NASA needs to streamline their PR. Half the time it seems well done, modern, and in touch, while the other half of the time it seems like it's written from a space-race era PR manual.

Comment: [Why was this question so quickly put on hold, and without comments, guidance, or suggestions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1389/12102)

Comment: Nothing personal, but I will vote to re-close if this is re-opened.

Comment: @DavidHammen I understand, but during that time we just may see some additional insightful answers posted. One good answer has been posted already, so I'm curious why you're so confident that only opinion-based answers are possible.

Comment: @DavidHammen - OK, maybe Mr. Bridenstine expects the U.S. stock market to stall, and he's waiting for his pizza ;)

Answer (score 5):

Read: https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2019/05/nasa-briefly-crew-dragon-anomaly-spacex-schedule/

NASA is waiting for progress on the Crew Dragon capsule (which exploded during an abort test in April 2019) and Mr. Bridenstine is upset that Mr. Musk is spending effort on Starship instead of delivering on the NASA contract.  Bridenstine expressed a similar sentiment (poor communications with SpaceX) at a public meeting in May (following the test 'anomaly'), but his remarks were cut from the video.

Comment: Read: [SpaceX’s response to Crew Dragon explosion unfairly maligned by head of NASA](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-crew-dragon-response-maligned-by-nasa/) starting with **A Trip Down Memory Lane** and also [Boeing may have used a lobbying firm to plant a scathing opinion piece about SpaceX in US news outlets. At stake are billions of dollars in NASA contracts.](https://www.businessinsider.com/boeing-may-have-used-firm-to-plant-anti-spacex-oped-2018-10?r=US&IR=T)

Comment: One has to admit Crew Dragon just isn't very *shiny*.

Comment: Who wrote that and what are their sources?